# Is it ok to use a zero conditional in this case?

Tags: conditional-constructions

Take this sentence structure:

> When X happens, Z typically happens.

It is a zero conditional because it uses "when" and the present simple.

According to the rule, a zero conditional can only be used when the result of the condition is always true (correct me if I am wrong).

The above sentence is using "typically", which implies that the result of the condition is not always true.

Knowing this, is using a zero conditional in the above sentence wrong? If so, how should it be rewritten?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your example. You can use adverbs of frequency with the zero conditional.  There is no rule against this.

Comment: related: [Can I delete some words from this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/331481/)

Comment: Can you say how 'Z typically happens' is without condition? Had you said 'Z always happens' that might have been acceptable but how is 'typically' unconditional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP needs to be corrected! It's ***not*** true that *a zero conditional can only be used when the result of the condition is **always** true.*

It's just that we do in fact use the "zero conditional" for "universal truths" like ***If you heat ice it melts***. But we also use it for things that ***often*** happen (with no qualification).

AND we can explicitly qualify the likelihood of a less probable scenario using Present Tense throughout: *If you heat a stone it **sometimes** cracks* (it doesn't have to be *...it **will** sometimes crack*).

---

As has often been pointed out here and on ELU, "numbered conditionals" aren't very useful in the context of learning English. Hardly any native Anglophones know or care what they are, and in any case they don't cover all scenarios or syntactic constructions. Don't spend too much time learning the specific contexts covered by constructions which have been assigned numbers, and don't assume a "usage summary" applies to *every* situation.

Comment: No. I don't think formal / informal is a relevant concept here.